# How to update values in a list for everyone's personalizedView?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

We have a custom list that has a personalized view of important links for each of our employees.

ListName is "Important Links". Column names are: URL, OwningUser, etc. 
For example, CNN could be one of these links. It would be in the list 4000 times(thats the number of employees we have). If by chance CNN changed it's url how would I be able to change the value 4000 times for each employee?

Is there some kind of Powershell script I can run?

Thanks,
Ninel

Answer (score 1):

You just update the hyperlink in the item, there isn't a need to run a script or anything to update the information in all the views because they all point to the same list item.  All it takes is one edit by anyone with contribute ability to cause the information to be updated in everyone's personal views.  Those are just private slices of the same public data.

Couldn't users maintain their own data in their My Sites by creating their own links list? I don't understand why you need to have 3999 duplicate entries in a list.

Comment: It was set up like this. I have a personalizedview and allitems view

Comment: How are the personalized views defined? Where OwningUser=[Me]?

Comment: It was set up like this. I have a personalizedview and allitems view. The CNN links are on the 4000 personalized views so each person has a link. So I do need to update each of the links.

Comment: Yes, so each employee has their own view.

Comment: Wow, I feel bad for you inheriting that. Poor information architecture.  I'd probably just do it by updating 1 item, then copying that down to all records in datasheet view.  I'd also consider revising the list architecture so that OwningUser can be blank and act as being available to everyone.  Then the personal view filter can be owninguser is empty or owninguser=[me] to help cut down on some of the duplicate data, but realistically this should be stored in a my site.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else runs into the same issue and needs to update the URL of a list here's my Powershell script:

```
    $spWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://mysite
    $spList = $spWeb.GetList("/Lists/My Links User List/allitems.aspx") 
    foreach($Item in $spList.Items )
    {
       $ofldurl= new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue($Item["URL"])
            $ofldurl.URL = $ofldurl.URL.Replace("http://mysite/Department.aspx?dept=24", "http://mysite/PatientCareServices/PatientSupportServices/PatientEducation")
       $item["URL"] = $ofldurl
       $item.update()
    }
    $spWeb.Dispose()
```